# MongoDB aggregating only data within the standard deviation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

So I have a set of offers with a 'price' attribute. I want to aggregate them to get the min/max/avg etc.. however I only want to select the ones who are in the range of a deviation, for example, average +- standard deviation.
Now there is the `$stdDevPop` key, but it only works correctly in the group stage where I can't use it anymore to filter the incorrect offers out. Is there a way to do this within the aggregation framework, without having to make another aggregation (and then just using the match stage for example) before that? If not, how is it affecting the performance, I do this over a quite large set of offers.

Comment: You realize that you can store the result of `$stdDevPop` in a new field at that pipeline stage, right? If you store the result in a field `stdDev`, then you can use it in an expression in the next pipeline state via `"$stdDev"`.

Comment: isnt that only the project stage? it doesnt work that way in praxis sadly, its only for 1 document (or more if you specify them)

Comment: No, it works on the `$group` stage. Check out the documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/stdDevPop/#use-in-group-stage

Comment: So you suggest 2 group stages? Group with stdDev -> Match -> Group min/max/avg?

Comment: Yes, that would do the trick. The grouping would reduce the document count, however, so you would like want to collect the prices with `$push` as well to reuse them, so you would do stdDev/push -> unwind -> match -> min/max/avg.

Comment: Alright, do you anything of the perfomance implications this have? are they neglible or a big performance hit?

Comment: Every pipeline stage will add additional overhead. That being said, I wouldn't expect the performance to vary by much more than a relatively constant factor. Your biggest concern is going to be the size of the data you're processing, as the `$push` operation could cause your documents in that pipeline stage to exceed the 16MB limit if the data is sufficiently large.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer to the above question but just adding just in case someone like me who wants to calculate simple std, land here:

db.collectionName.aggregate([ { $group: { _id: "myStd", myStd: { $stdDevSamp: "$my_field_name" } } } ])